# What is causing my files to save to My Document instead of the specified path?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to coding (learning on my own and as I go) and have a small problem I just don't get.  I have a code that has been working for a while and now seems to not work.  I created a Service work order sheet to help keep accurate tabs on jobs for our service department.  The code is pretty simple, they user enters all information in the cells they need.  When finished they can press a button that updates a separate file.  Press another and it saves a copy of the active work sheet to a specified networked location, prints copies, saves the work sheet according to a specified cell, then clears specified cells and updates the PO# cell.

The code has worked  well until it stopped saving the file copies to the  directory indicated and I don't know why it changed.

```
Sub SaveWorkOrderByAddress()
ChDir "\\BG-PC\SharedDocs\Service work orders\Service work orders"
Dim NewFN As Variant
Dim stFileName As String

'Save a new copy
NewFN = Range("C2").Value & ".xlsx"
stFileName = Range("C2").Value & ".xlsx"
If Dir(stFileName) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File already exists, please rename."
Else
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        PrintCurrentWO
        NextWorkOrderNumber
        ThisWorkbook.Save
End If
```

Any help would be most appreciated and again I am new so I am sorry if it's a newb mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the working directory doesn't help here. Just combine the path with the filename when calling `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`.

Like this:

```
NewFN = "\\BG-PC\SharedDocs\Service work orders\Service work orders\" & Range("C2").Value & ".xlsx"
```